# Pandas dataframe does not separate columns according to comma in csv

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a matrix according to the table from CSV data

```
COEFFICIENT MATRIX 
,0,1,2,3,4
0,0.00876623398408,0.525189723661,0.528495953628,0.94228622319,0.0379073884588
1,0.434693398364,0.77017930965,0.00847865052462,0.544319471939,0.858970329817
2,0.978091233581,0.900800004769,0.504567295427,0.65499490009,0.397203736755
3,0.671510258373,0.554713361673,0.377098128478,0.246977226206,0.535900353082
...
5000,0.791781572037,0.70262685963,0.218775600741,0.19802280762,0.68177855465
```

I'm using pandas for reading csv and return a matrix. Instead of getting matrix.shape = 5001*5, I got 5002*1.

How to make pandas dataframe  separate the right number of columns according to comma from CSV, and don't count the header (after the table title) as the first row?

```
 input = pd.read_csv(coeff_file, skiprows=0)
 input_mat = input.as_matrix()

 print input.shape
 print type(input)

 print input_mat.shape
 print type(input_mat)
```

return

```
(5002, 1)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(5002, 1)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `skiprows=1`,  `skiprows=[0]` or `header=1` parameters in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(coeff_file, skiprows=1, index_col=0)
print (df)
             0         1         2         3         4
0     0.008766  0.525190  0.528496  0.942286  0.037907
1     0.434693  0.770179  0.008479  0.544319  0.858970
2     0.978091  0.900800  0.504567  0.654995  0.397204
3     0.671510  0.554713  0.377098  0.246977  0.535900
5000  0.791782  0.702627  0.218776  0.198023  0.681779
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(coeff_file, header=1, index_col=0)
print (df)
             0         1         2         3         4
0     0.008766  0.525190  0.528496  0.942286  0.037907
1     0.434693  0.770179  0.008479  0.544319  0.858970
2     0.978091  0.900800  0.504567  0.654995  0.397204
3     0.671510  0.554713  0.377098  0.246977  0.535900
5000  0.791782  0.702627  0.218776  0.198023  0.681779
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), skiprows=[0], index_col=0)
print (df)
             0         1         2         3         4
0     0.008766  0.525190  0.528496  0.942286  0.037907
1     0.434693  0.770179  0.008479  0.544319  0.858970
2     0.978091  0.900800  0.504567  0.654995  0.397204
3     0.671510  0.554713  0.377098  0.246977  0.535900
5000  0.791782  0.702627  0.218776  0.198023  0.681779
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much. Just want to ask a little more. I try skiprows=range(0,1) just now, and it works too. Anyway, why skiprows=1 works without including 0?

Comment: Hmm, I think you need add value `0` to list - docs says `Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file`